# How to copy a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have 2 function:

Func.h

```
 struct Ex
    {
      int a;
      int b;
    }
```

Func.cpp

```
void Copy(Ex ** ex1, Ex *ex2)
{
   //
}

void Init(Ex **ex)
{
  *ex = (Ex*)malloc(3*sizeof(Ex));
  Ex *ex2 = (Ex*)malloc(sizeof(Ex));
  Copy(&(*ex+1), ex2)              //error here
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I fix this error?

Thank You!!!

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: `&(*Ex+1)` <-- did you mean `ex` with a common `e`?

Comment: @crashmstr you're very right, but then again , OP says `Func.cpp`...confusing.

Comment: `Copy(&(*Ex+1), ex2) `  --> did (_not_) you mean `Copy(&(*ex+1), ex2);`

Comment: The struct isn't a typedef.

Comment: You'll have to explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: So the problem you're having is not really the *copying* of the structure? It's the expression you use for an argument to a function you call (doesn't really matter what the function does)? You might want to update the title to better reflect the problem you're having.

Comment: Is this C like your tag suggests, or is this C++ like your supposed file name suggests?

Comment: Also, when you post questions about build errors, include the *complete* and *unedited* error output in the question. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Thank you everybody
I want to when I call Copy function the value (*ex+1)->a and (*ex+1)->b was changed

Comment: The problem is the concept of `copy` makes no sense, since neither `ex` or `ex2` have any values (they are just blocks of uninitialized memory when you call `Copy`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty you are having is because your are not creating **3 pointers to of type `struct Ex`** in your `Init` function. You are just creating a pointer to **a block of memory large enough to hold 3 struct Ex**. That is fine, but you cannot rely on normal array syntax to pass or access the values in `ex`. **You** are responsible for providing the pointer address to whichever value you want within `ex`.

The following is a quick example of your code. `Init` has been changed to take the additional arguments of **the number structs to create size for**, and **initial values for members `a` and `b`**.

Personally, I find it easier to create the original struct in `main` as `struct Ex **ex` and then pass the address as a triple pointer to `Init`, but that is up to you. Keeping with your approach, take a look at the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Ex
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

/* simple copy funciton */
void Copy(struct Ex *ex1, struct Ex *ex2)
{
    memcpy (ex1, ex2, sizeof (struct Ex));
}

/* arguments, address of *ex, num to create, initial values .a=va, .b=vb */
void Init(struct Ex **ex, size_t n, int va, int vb)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t offset = sizeof **ex;

    *ex = malloc (n * offset);
    struct Ex *ex2 = malloc (sizeof *ex2);

    ex2-> a = va;
    ex2-> b = vb;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Copy (*ex + i * offset, ex2);
}

int main (void) {

    struct Ex *ex = NULL;
    size_t offset = sizeof *ex;
    size_t i = 0;

    Init (&ex, 3, 5, 6);  /* initialize 3 ex, with initial values of 5, 6 */

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf ("\n (ex +%2lu)->a : %d\n (ex +%2lu)->b : %d\n",
                i * offset, (ex + i * offset)->a,  i * offset, (ex + i * offset)->b);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/structinitcopy

 (ex + 0)->a : 5
 (ex + 0)->b : 6

 (ex + 8)->a : 5
 (ex + 8)->b : 6

 (ex +16)->a : 5
 (ex +16)->b : 6
```